# Update several objects with REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to know if there is a way (and of course if it is a good practice) to update a 'big' list of objects(>100 for example) through a single REST API call.

I know the REST API defines http GET,POST,PUT,DELETE

At the moment I do individuals calls to PUT with each single object.

May this create a lack of performance?

I found an article about [PATCH](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-dusseault-http-patch-14.html) Method HTTP , but I don't know if it is what I exactly need.

The technologies I am using are:
ASP .NET WEBAPI2
AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP-Put` and `Post` should be the way to go.
But since you are updating a collection, see if you can update the collection itself and not every entry in it. If it is a collection like "top 100 movies in 2014" this collection should have an id.

> At the moment I do individuals calls to PUT with each single object.
>   May this create a lack of performance?

Yes it does, for each request you have an overhead of information that has to be sent.

Comment: Then, a way could be to associate an Id for the collection I retrieve from the server so I can use the PUT?

Comment: yes, but don't to this if you just updating a few entries, then multiple puts for each object could be faster.